# Why do symbols look ugly in gvim?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, unicode, font

I'm on Windows 7 with Vim 7.4, and Unicode symbols with the [Hack](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/Hack) font look awful. Am I missing a setting somewhere? Is there a way to improve this?

For reference, this is gvim:

[image: gvim]

and this is atom:

[image: atom]

I've also done the same with the Consolas font, and it's still bad.

This issue also exists in terminal vim, but it is slightly better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a recent Vim, you may try to enable DirectX rendering. It should improve "wide" font rendering, among other things. Here's an example `vimrc` snip:

```
if has("gui_running")
    set guioptions=icpM
    if has('win32') || has('win64')
        if (v:version == 704 && has("patch393")) || v:version > 704
            set renderoptions=type:directx,level:0.75,gamma:1.25,contrast:0.25,
                        \geom:1,renmode:5,taamode:1
        endif
endif
```

*Reference* `:h rop`

---

Some other remarks, more generic, which may or may not be useful in your case:

Font spacing (horizontal, vertical) sometimes is not the same between Linux, Mac and Windows (in Vim, but also happens with other apps, e.g. Emacs). You can tweak those using `set linespace=...` (vertical) and, (only) if you use [Kaoriya's gVim build](http://www.kaoriya.net/software/vim/), `set charspace=...` (horizontal). This may indirectly improve font appearance.

Comment: Interesting. Well, it looks MUCH better now.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me setting `renderoptions=type:directx` has a big performance impact.